# Visual Studio Code Source Controle: Mange the Right Directories

Tags: visual-studio-code

### My Setup (simplified)

```
/home/mogoh/ <- git repo
/home/mogoh/src/project.code-workspace
/home/mogoh/src/website <- git repo
/home/mogoh/src/dir2 <- git repo
```

#### project.code-workspace

```
{
  "folders": [
    {"path": "/home/mogoh/src/website"},
    {"path": "/home/mogoh/src/dir2"},
  ],
}
```

### The Problem

Visual Studio Code now lists only `website` and `mogoh` in my „Source Controle“ tab, even if my home folder is not part of my workspace.
And it does not list `dir2` even if it is part of my workspace.

Further, every file of `dir2` is grayed out as if it would not be under version controle.

The problem started once I created a git repository in my home folder.

### Not a solution

Delete:

```
/home/mogoh/.config/Code
/home/mogoh/.vscode/
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it somehow:

```
"git.ignoredRepositories": [
    "/home/mogoh"
]
```